# Scanner reports security flaw in netty-handler-4.1.65.Final

Tags: security, netty

I would like to use library netty-handler-4.1.65.Final (indirectly via the Vert.x libraries), but our Nexus Sonatype server is denying access saying the following:

"The `netty-handler` package is vulnerable to Improper Certificate Validation. The `newHandler` methods in `SslContext.class` do not verify hostnames by default when generating a new `SSLEngine`. An attacker can exploit this as part of a Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) attack to spoof their identify and gain access to or modify sensitive data."

Is this being addressed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I didn't search hard enough - this will be enabled by default in version 5.